# Missing info.plist values aren't missing

Tags: ios, privacy, info.plist

My iOS app is crashing with:

> 2023-08-04 11:22:48.611193-0400 SitePoint-iOS-Sample[1626:556052] [access] This app has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description.  The app's Info.plist must contain an NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

... but I do have that value in my Info.plist. How do I get these settings recognized?

[image: Proof of Info.plist values and more crash data]

Answer (score 0):

My Info.plist file wasn't registered in my Xcode project; setting its path in my `Build Settings -> Packaging, Info.plist File` got this working.

Comment: A good way to have found this out (and what I was going to suggest) would be to have looked into _the built app itself_ and read its Info.plist.